# Node.js Sequelize Cannot read Property foreach of nulll

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

**THIS IS ERROR
TypeError: C:\users\gaffer\desktop\6th Semester\GafferCart\views\admin\add_product.ejs:22**

**Executing (default): SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM `Products` AS `Product`;
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `slug`, `desc`, `category`, `price`, `images` FROM `Products` AS `Product` LIMIT 1;
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `slug` FROM `Categories` AS `Category` LIMIT 1;**

```
    20|         <label for="">Category</label>

   21|         <select name="category" class="form-control">

 >> 22|             <% categories.forEach(function(cat){ %>

    23|                 <option value="<%= cat.slug %>"><%= cat.title %
</option>
    24|             <% }); %>
    25|         </select
```

>

**Cannot read property 'forEach' of null**

```
          // Get Product model
          var Product = require('../models/product');

        // Get Product model
        var Category = require('../models/category');

            /*
            * Get products index 
            */

            router.get('/',function(req,res){

                var count;

                models.Product.count(function(c){
                    count=c;
                })
                //models.product.find
                models.Product.find({
           attributes: 
                    ['id','title','slug','desc','category','price','images']
                })
                .then(function(products){
                    res.render('admin/products',{
                        products:products,
                        count:count
                    });
                });
            });

                /*
                * GET add product
                */
    router.get('/add-product', function (req, res) {

        var title = "";
        var desc = "";
        var price = "";

        models.Category.find({
            attributes:['id','title','slug']
        })   
        //.then((categories)=>{   both are giving same errors

           .then(function(categories){
            res.render('admin/add_product', {
                title: title,
                desc: desc,
                categories: categories,
                price: price
            });

        });
 });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, to increase your changes of getting a decent answer, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your categories object is null, please console the object.

Comment: I just rendered res.json(categories);

Comment: {"id":1,"title":"asad","slug":"asad"}  and it gives me this answer

Comment: These all fields are from Products Please Noman Maqsood check my second Get add Products

 res.json(categories);
                    // res.render('admin/add_product', {
                    //     title: title,
                    //     desc: desc,
                    //     categories: categories,
                    //     price: price
                    // });